# Scope Variable undefined in angularjs typescript controller class of directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript, angularjs-controller

I have created wrapper directive over ag grid as below

```
function MyDirective(): ng.IDirective {
    var directive = <ng.IDirective>{
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<div style="width: 100%; height: 400px;" ag-grid="vm.agGridOptions" class="ag-fresh ag-basic"></div>',
        scope: { gridOptions: '=', rowClicked: "&", api: '=' },
        controller: gridController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true
    }
    return directive;
}
angular.module("angularWithTS").directive("myDirective", MyDirective);
```

My controller class looks like below:

```
 export class gridController {
    public agGridOptions: any = {};
    public api: any = {};
    public gridOptions: any;
    public rowClicked: any;
    constructor() {
        this.Process();
    }
    private Process() {
        /*****Contoller Logic*****/
        var columnDefs = commonFunctions.convertToAgColumns(this.gridOptions.columnDefinitions);

        this.agGridOptions.enableSorting = true;
        this.agGridOptions.editable = true;
        this.agGridOptions.enableColResize = true;
        this.agGridOptions.columnDefs = columnDefs;
        /*****Contoller Logic*****/

        /*****Exposed Events*****/
        this.agGridOptions.onRowClicked = function (event) {
            this.rowClicked({ index: event.rowIndex });
        };
        /*****Exposed Events*****/


        /*****Public Api*****/
        this.api = {
            populateData: function (options) {
                this.agGridOptions.api.setRowData(options.rowData);
            }
        }
    }
    /*****Public Api*****/
}
```

My directive tag in html looks like below

```
<my-directive grid-options="options" api="gridApi"></my-directive>
```

Question: When i tries to call api method populateData() in controller scope variables like agGridOptions is undefined and then rest is not working.
Why variable agGridOptions is not available when i call public api ?
Please help.. its working fine when i code normal js functions way controller but not working with typescript class controller. Any help would be appreciated

I m calling controller method like below:

```
     $scope.gridApi = {};
  $scope.options = {};
            $scope.options.columnDefinitions = $scope.columnDefinitions;
    $http.get("monthlySales.json").then(function (response) {
        $timeout(function () {          
            $scope.options.rowData = response.data;
            $scope.gridApi.populateData($scope.options);
        },2000);
    });
```

When controller invoked first time all the values of variables in controller like gridOptions,agGridOptions are properly get.
But agGridOptions getting undefined when i call api populateData to show fetched data.

Comment: I use typescript as well, but currently @ novice level, I know that to pass "this" you need to declare your function like this: populateData = () => {this.agGridOptions.api.setRowData(options.rowData); } (the equal & greater than is the key element here)

Comment: (it sounds disrespecting when I read this again but I am just not sure about your syntax, maybe it is something i am not familiar with...)

Comment: hi @ZivWeissman thanks for the reply. but when i tried  this.api = {
                populateData(options:any) => {
                    this.agGridOptions.api.setRowData(options.rowData);
                }
            } its syntax error..Not sure about this

Comment: try this: this.api = {
            populateData:(options) => {
                this.agGridOptions.api.setRowData(options.rowData);
            }
        }

Comment: Hi @ZivWeissman I had tried but still this.agGridOptions is undefined when i call populateData method later. Whats wrong any help would be appreciated

Comment: if u place debugger in your function, and you hover on "this"? (should be _this in the JS) what element you are seeing?

Comment: Hello @ZivWeissman, thanks for your kind reply .. I have checked in debugger and found that _this object contains objects like "agGridOptions", "api", "gridOptions" and rowClicked function...But this object contains only populateData...Why so? so need to use _this instead of this? How to use ?

Comment: hello @ZivWeissman, I have used  this.api = {  populateData: (options: any) => { var __this = this;                  __this.agGridOptions.api.setRowData(options.rowData); } } so its accessible..but when i use same thing in onRowClicked then "rowClicked" not available..probably agGridOptions.onRowClicked not properly defined?

Comment: ts automatically transfer (this) into (_this) when u use '() =>'. The 'this' you are seeing is just the function 'populateData', try this link: http://goo.gl/eBwQn0

Comment: Hey @ZivWeissman .. you are genius .. thanks for your help and my question is resolved..How to mark your reply as answer or how to give u points?

Comment: I will write an answer now. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'this' you are calling to in your function is referring to the function itself, and not your controller-

```
this.api = {
        populateData: function (options) {
            this.agGridOptions.api.setRowData(options.rowData); //(this = populateData function)
        }
    }
```

The syntax should be changed to () => (this will make typescript compiler to 'transfer' the this, it will become _this in the js file)

It should look like this:

```
this.api.populateData =  (options)=> {
            this.agGridOptions.api.setRowData(options.rowData);    
    }
```